# Unable to run Chrome and Firefox Browsers in Selenium Test Project

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

namespace SeleniumTidBits
{
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
  static IWebDriver driverFF;
  static IWebDriver driverGC;

    [AssemblyInitialize]
    public static void SetUp(TestContext context)
    {

        driverFF = new FirefoxDriver(); 
        driverGC = new ChromeDriver();

    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestFireFoxDriver()
    {
        driverFF.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
        driverFF.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys("Selenium");
        driverFF.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestChormeDriver()
    {
        driverGC.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
        driverGC.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys("Selenium");
        driverGC.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
    }
}
```

}

Error:

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qMNa.jpg)

I'm just trying to run some random scripts to test webdrivers of Selenium. I'm using VS 2012 and i have imported driver from Nuget package.

Comment: Do you get an error message? Also, please edit your post, select all and press Ctrl + K.

Answer (score 0):

For starting the test in Firefox, You will have to download geckodriver from here: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases and use this code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", [path to the driver]);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Answer (score -1):

That Error states that Selenium WebDriver could not find the Firefox driver in your project folder. 
Also, Webdriver  no longer supports the default Firefox Driver. They are currently working on a new driver, called Marionette, for their new Gecko engine.(You have the link in the error)

More details on Marionette you can find here: [Marionette](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette)

If you want to use the default driver, you should downgrade your Firefox. Version 45.0.1 works fine for me. And you should get Selenium Webdriver 2.53, the one you are using is 3.0.0 (The latest from NUget)

Comment: Downgrading FF is not a solution, it's a workaround. Most of your customers are going to be using the newest version of FF not FF45.

Comment: Sorry mate, but I don't agree. Since Webdriver 3.0.0 and from Firefox 48 on, only gecko is supported, what other solution is? Either you upgrade your driver to geckodriver or you downgrade to the previous version. Also, if you have a better solution I'm happy to hear it, and I'm eager to learn something new. Anyway is better than just voting down. Cheers.